# StackApplet - Monitor your reputation and get notified of comments. [v1.5 released]

Tags: discussion, applet

> ### StackApplet 1.5 released!
>
> Be sure to visit the [downloads page](https://launchpad.net/stackapplet/+download) to give the latest version a try. If you are able to translate StackApplet to another language, that would be awesome! If not, you can still help by reporting bugs and issues that you come across.

I want to share with you all a nice applet I made for this site. <sup>(Well, not for this site *specifically*, but it applies.)</sup>

It's called StackApplet. It's a status icon that notifies you of answers, comments people post to you, and reputation changes.

Here is the package: (for both 32 and 64 bit installs)

http://launchpad.net/stackapplet/1.5/1.5/+download/stackapplet_1.5_all.deb

The package is also in my PPA (*BUT* it is an older version):

```
ppa:george-edison55/george-edison
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

**Note:** to add this site, click the icon and click preferences. Type "askubuntu" into the site name field. Type your user ID into the other. Then click "Add to List" and click "OK".

**Second note:** The code for this app is on [Launchpad](http://launchpad.net/stackapplet).

**Third note:** StackApplet 1.4 is in the Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric) repositories.

Comment: Cool. Interested in having that officially packaged in Debian/Ubuntu? Shoot me an email at `myusername@ubuntu.com`

Comment: @lfaraone: ...and done.

Comment: We need a KDE applet too :D I might even write it

Comment: @txwikinger: Too late, one of the good people at StackApps wrote one: http://stackapps.com/questions/117/stacktray-the-stackoverflow-tray-application

Comment: @lfaraone: Did you get my email?

Comment: @George Edison: yes, I did.

Comment: I'm using LXDE. Could this be made to work in any systray?

Comment: @mac: Well, not without rewriting a fair amount of it. Also, I have no experience working with LXDE.

Comment: where is the source code for it?

Comment: @txwikinger: It's a Python script - so the application *is* the source code. It's in the package provided in the link above.

Comment: Well, if you make something that works out of the systray, it should work in any window manager -- GNOME, KDE, LXDE, Fluxbox, etc. -- just like Network Manager.

Jorge Castro mentioned below that you could use App Indicators. I believe that is WM-independent.

Comment: @mac: Would you be able to point me to some resources for learning more about App Indicators?

Comment: Hey, George, sorry I didn't get back to you sooner. Somehow I wasn't notified of your reply.  :-/  I don't know much about App Indicators, so I guess this page would be as good a place to start as any: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators  Sorry I can't be any more help.

Comment: Does it work on maverick?

Comment: @ssj: I don't know. Haven't tried it. I don't see why it wouldn't.

Comment: This is brilliant

Comment: I can't get the version (1.2.0) from Maverick's repositories to work.  "Adding ubuntu.stackexchange / mgedmin" -> `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'HTTPError' objects`

Comment: Turns out I didn't know my username... oops!

Comment: Then again the only username that works is "136", which is a user*id*, certainly, but I wouldn't call it a user*name*...

Comment: @Marius: The version in Maverick is quite far behind, I'm afraid - recent improvements have fixed this issue.

Comment: This is an excellent idea. +1

Comment: Version 1.4 gave me a whole bunch of warnings. I did not click on Ignore and Install just in case.

Comment: @CYREX: Warnings? How are you installing it?

Comment: Clicked on the Link above (The http://launchpad.net/stackapplet/1.4/1.4/+download/stackapplet_1.4.0_all.deb one) opened in Software Center and clicked on Install. Then it gave a bunch of errors like:  

Lintian check results for   /home/cyrex/Downloads/stackapplet_1.4.0_all (1).deb:  
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/ 1000/1000  
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/ 1000/1000  
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid   usr/share/applications/ 1000/1000  
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid    
And in continues on..

Comment: @CYREX: Ah, you're right. I'll make sure this is fixed for the next version. In the meantime - there is a version *in* the official repositories that you can use in Natty. Just run `'sudo apt-get install stackapplet'`.

Comment: I am helping with Russian translations time to time now.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS: Excellent, thank you!

Comment: Can somebody review this translation? Possibly on [russian.se]?

Comment: @NathanOsman: Is it only me, or is there a problem on Ubuntu 14.04?  Nothing shows in the right corner.

Comment: Does it still work ?

Answer (score 5):

A maverick Version would be great.

Comment: Has anyone tried it in Maverick? I'm curious to know if it works or not - it *should* work, but that's not the same as actually testing it.

Comment: It's working for me in Maverick.

Comment: I am using the deb package not the PPA

Comment: If you can hang tight for a few weeks, it looks like this will actually be included in the Maverick repositories.

Comment: I uploaded the package to Debian Unstable, it's since been synced into Maverick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting an error with the latest (1.4) version:

> There was an error retrieving information from StackAuth when StackApplet was initialized.
>
> The preferences dialog cannot be displayed.
>
> Please note that this is not an error in StackApplet - either a misconfigured Internet connection or StackAuth failure are likely the problem.

I'm running maverick, and my internet connection seems fine.

Comment: This is sometimes caused by the API servers going down temporarily. Try again in a few hours.

Comment: Yeah, that was it.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why I can't connect this to my Programmers SE account? The icon just says 'Please wait...' endlessly.

Also, how do I get a context menu like that seen in the screenshot?

Comment: This tool has gone though a whole lot of updates since last this post was updated.

Comment: Marco is right. The latest version is [here](https://launchpad.net/stackapplet).

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to add a text display of the total rep for a selected site to the indicator's icon (similar to what the system temperature indicator does)?

Comment: Yes, this is planned for StackApplet 1.6.