# Tools for Ask Ubuntu

Tags: discussion, tools

As some of you know, I have created some tools for Stack Exchange sites (like Ask Ubuntu) on [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com).

What tools have been developed for Ask Ubuntu, or are especially useful to Ask Ubuntu users?

Comment: we have a whole site for APIs and apps for the Stack Exchange engine -- at http://stackapps.com . If your add-on works on askubuntu, it will also work on Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault, and any other SE 2.0 website: http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: Thanks Jeff for your comment. I'm already registered there and I'm aware of the compatibility, but I wanted to make an add-on specifically for askubuntu. Nevertheless, I'm considering making a general version in the future.

Answer (score 29):

StackApplet for Linux

[StackApplet - Monitor your reputation and get notified of comments. [v1.5 released]](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18/monitor-your-reputation-and-get-notified-of-comments)

[image]

Comment: I've just added the applet via ppa. It's very nice on my panel. @George Edison, thank you!

Comment: wow, I luv these applet

Comment: Is a very useful tool like stackstats but how can I hide it from the panel when I have the option "Register StackApplet in the Messaging Menu" activated. That way i save space in the panel and stackapplet only shows in the messaging menu which I find better.

Answer (score 26):

For everybody who can't get enough of *the numbers*, there's now

## StackStats

Great name, I know :P

[image]

Usage:

- Download the script from **[[image] Here](https://github.com/sfstpala/StackStats/raw/master/stackstats.py)** and save it somewhere
- Execute it like this:

  ```
  python /home/username/stackstats.py --site=askubuntu.com --user=41
  ```

  Where `/home/username/stackstats.py` is the absolute path to the script, `askubuntu.com` is any stackexchange site and [`41`](https://askubuntu.com/users/41/marcoceppi) is your user-id.

  - To find out your user id, go to your profile page. It should be in the URL, i.e. `askubuntu.com/users/1067/stefano-palazzo`.
- I recommend you set up an alias in your `~/.bash_aliases`, like this:

  ```
  alias ask-stats="python ~/stackstats.py --site=askubuntu.com --user=1067"
  ```

Hope you like it, let me know if something's wrong as always:-)

---

I've tested it on fresh installs of

- 10.04 Lucid
- 10.10 Maverick
- 11.04 Natty
- Debian 6.0

Please edit this list, if you are running anything else

---

StackStats now [lives on GitHub](https://github.com/sfstpala/StackStats). Also, it's now licensed under the terms of the [GNU GPL v3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html). Please hack if you like, and contribute your changes back.

If you see a bug, and you know python and github, *fix it*. ;)

Comment: Does this use the API?

Comment: @George yes, no tricks here :)

Comment: Cool. I like the fact that you chose Python.

Comment: Awesome! It's on GitHub. Totally forking this.

Answer (score 18):

I'm proud to announce the first askubuntu.com extension, developed for Firefox, Opera and Chrome.

The extension, called [AskUbuntu Add-on](http://www.webgapps.org/addons/askubuntu), allows to easily track user info and questions.

The extension that displays user reputation/badges, monitor activity and provides an easy access to unanswered questions, user questions, user favorites and user tags from an askubuntu.com account.

**Home page**: http://www.webgapps.org/addons/askubuntu

**Mozilla gallery**: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/242568/

**Opera gallery**: [https://addons.opera.com/addons/extensions/details/askubuntu-add-on...](https://addons.opera.com/addons/extensions/details/askubuntu-add-on/?display=en)

**Google gallery**: [https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/...](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/hamgohmiimamjpabgncmklojoibjknon)

Please let me know what you think about it.

> **Note:** some Gnome users might experience diminished functionality if their
>   Firefox does not show icons in menus,
>   since the icons are indicators of new
>   activity. To solve this problem visit:
>   [Where is the gnome option to display icons in menus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8586/where-is-the-gnome-option-to-display-icons-in-menus)

Firefox

[image: Firefox]

Opera

[image: Opera]

Chrome

[image: Chrome]

Comment: I'm already working on the next version, which will have some context menu options. For instance, while reading a question in the site it will be possible to right-click on the page and set that question to be ignored, so it won't show in the extension menus and won't trigger alerts when updated. Next version will also fully support meta.askubuntu and the user will be able to easily switch between meta and askubuntu

Comment: Thanks a lot; I love this extension. A reminder (maybe two) for the new users to be on the safe side: When I installed the extensiom, it appeared on the right uppermost part of the window, just near the search bar, somewhat different than what we see in the screenshot. First you have to enter your user ID via Preferences of the extension. User ID is the number you see in the url when you visit your profile page on askubuntu.com.

Comment: Thanks for these reminders. You see the extension widget in the bottom of Firefox on my screenshot, because I'm using Firefox 4, in which there is no more statusbar. The statusbar has been replaced by an add-ons bar, which means you can drag any toolbar extension widget to it. I have included a code to auto-add the widget to the main toolbar as you described, but you can move it around by right-clicking on the toolbar and selecting the the "customize" option.

Comment: AskUbuntu Add-on 1.0.1 was released today and is available for download. This version brings several new features - http://askubuntu-extension.blogspot.com/2010/10/askubuntu-add-on-101-released.html

Comment: 1.0.1 is even better. I was not aware of the new version for four days. My bad.

Comment: This extension has a page [here](http://stackapps.com/questions/1699/askubuntu-add-on-for-firefox) and registered users of stackapps.com can vote for it. I did.

Comment: @marenostrum Thanks a lot. There is a minor bug in version 1.0.1, that has been fixed for the next version.

Comment: I have received several e-mails asking if I could provide versions of the extensions I develop for Chrome. So I have decided do it. AskUbuntu will be the first. Nevertheless, it will come after a version for Opera, which is already under development. Stay tuned.

Comment: I just received an e-mail stating that the extension has been approved by Mozilla, so no more account required to download and updates will be served with extensions updates :)

Comment: First version for Opera has been released!

Comment: The Opera version has been approved by Opera and is available for download at https://addons.labs.opera.com/addons/extensions/details/askubuntu-add-on/1.0.0/?display=en

Comment: Chrome version released! Also released a new version for Opera with a few improvements.

Comment: @lovinglinux It has been mentioned elsewhere on this meta site, but I noticed that your site refers to AskUbuntu, but the proper name is Ask Ubuntu (with a space).

Comment: This is a great extension. There are only two improvements I would request:

1) The ability to set a preference so that selecting something through the extension opens in a new tab instead of the current tab

2) An option to "ask a question" through the add-on, which when selected would just take you to the "ask a question" page. (I'm sorry if either of these already exist and I missed it)

Comment: @Jay Thanks for the feedback. You are not missing anything. The option to open in new tab is easy to implement, but the feature to ask questions I'm not so sure is possible. I will look into it tho.

Comment: Hi lovinglinux, your extension rocks!
I`m using on firefox and it works flawless :).
I was wondering how can I put the stats (points) in the bottom panel of firefox (like in your screenshots).

Comment: @Marcos Roriz, thanks. You need Firefox 4 to drag the extension launcher to the bottom, because the status bar has been replaced with the add-ons bar, which behaves like a regular toolbar.

Answer (score 11):

Ask Ubuntu is now available in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer.

http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/queries

The meta site is also available:

http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntumeta/queries

Answer (score 10):

### Droidstack

"An Android app that allows you to browse StackExchange websites in a very cool, native kind of way, while keeping a stackoverflow-like look & feel."

[image: screenshot]

**Links:**

[On StackApps...](https://stackapps.com/questions/585/droidstack-for-android)

[More screetshots...](https://foghina.imgur.com/droidstack)

[Video...](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SszXwWfdV_I)

[Source code and bug tracker...](http://code.google.com/p/droidstack/issues/list)

Install by scanning this QR code:

[image: qr barcode]

Answer (score 10):

We have a Lens for Unity in 11.04 now, which gives us desktop integration with the site. (This is handy for when you run into a question and remember that it's a dupe and you need to search it real quick.):

- [How do I install the Ask Ubuntu Unity Lens, and how do I use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31712/how-do-i-install-the-ask-ubuntu-unity-lens-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Answer (score 9):

I have written a tool that can be used to view the data dumps offline:

[StackExchange Data Dump Viewer - A Desktop Tool for Viewing the StackExchange Data Dumps](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/708/stackexchange-data-dump-viewer-a-desktop-tool-for-viewing-the-stackexchange-dat)

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: can you make a deb of this?

Answer (score 7):

There is a add on for chrome, not quite as good as this one, but it's a nice notifier, it works with any Stack Exchange site. I'm currently using this one to follow accounts on **Stackoverflow, Superuser and AskUbuntu**.

You can get it [here.](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/onbgjnpdcjdhjngbnhnhplnamagmiike#)

[image]

Comment: I prefer [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/587/new-q-google-chrome-extension-notifies-you-of-new-questions-of-interest) Chrome extension.

Comment: seems good. I´ll give it a spin  :)

Answer (score 7):

Google Chrome/Chromium Site Specific search.

- Open up Chrome's preferences.
- Click the "Manage Search Engines" button.

[image]

- Then, you'll need to change the `Ask Ubuntu` search engine information.

[image]

You'll see that I selected the third part - you'll need to change that to the following:

`http://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&ix=c2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=site%3Aaskubuntu.com+%s`

Boom, you've now replaced the default Ask Ubuntu search with Google's site-specific search.

Answer (score 6):

## StackMobile

Allows you to browse ubuntu.stackexchange.com through a mobile site designed for smartphones.

http://stackmobile.com/site.php?site=ubuntu.stackexchange

Screenshot:

[image]

*Screenshot from a webOS device.*

Answer (score 6):

### Google Custom Search Plugin (Site-specific search) for Firefox:

1. Create a file called `ask-ubuntu.xml` at `.mozilla/[profile.name]/searchplugins` folder. For example, `/home/nits/.mozilla/firefox/airbfsl5.default/searchplugins/ask-ubuntu.xml`
2. Add the following content in it.

   > ```
   >    <SearchPlugin xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/"
   > xmlns:os="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
   >     <os:ShortName>Ask Ubuntu</os:ShortName>
   >     <os:Description>Search Ask Ubuntu: Q&amp;A for Ubuntu users and developers</os:Description>
   >     <os:InputEncoding>UTF-8</os:InputEncoding>
   >     <os:Image width="16" height="16">data:image/x-icon;base64,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</os:Image>
   >     <os:Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="http://www.google.co.in/search?q=site%3Aaskubuntu.com+{searchTerms}">
   >     </os:Url>
   >     </SearchPlugin>
   > ```
3. Restart the browser
4. You'll see it among the list of search-engines in the search-engine plugin. And that's it, go nuts, quicker searching AU!

[image: list-of-search-engines]

[image: zoomed-view]

[image: search-results]

Answer (score 5):

> **Service has been discontinued.**
>
> Unfortunately due to lack of resources and time, this service has been discontinued. This answer will remain for historical purposes.

### Ask Ubuntu Search

Ask Ubuntu Search is a fast search engine for the site that uses the information in the data dumps and the API to respond to your search queries. Because it uses the API to keep up to date, the server uses data no older than two minutes to process your search query.

http://askubuntu.quickmediasolutions.com

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: This doesn't appear to be online anymore..

Comment: @Seth: updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 5):

## StackBrowser for Ubuntu Touch

*(StackApps post: https://stackapps.com/questions/4324/stackbrowser-for-ubuntu-touch)*

### About

StackBrowser allows you to explore the StackExchange network natively on Ubuntu Touch. Written in QML and JavaScript, it is mostly an excuse to play with the new [Ubuntu SDK](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/).

Currently you can:

- Browse and view recent questions
- Search questions by tag
- Browse, search, and view users

### Homepage

https://launchpad.net/stackbrowser

### Download

StackBrowser will be available in the Ubuntu Touch Software Center. It can be tested on a 13.10 Ubuntu desktop system, or on earlier releases if you have the SDK installed, by grabbing its source from Launchpad.

```
bzr branch lp:stackbrowser
cd stackbrowser
qmlscene stackbrowser.qml
```

### Screenshots

[image: home screen]

[image: user view]

[image: tag search]