# Is askubuntu available for offline viewing?

Tags: discussion, data-dump

Is there a offline version of askubuntu.com? Can I download it as in *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download)*? Or is there any app that mirror it ?

Comment: Is there somewhere better to point that link than directly to a **9 GB** data dump?

Comment: @ændrük Replaced with link to Wikipedia data dump page.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All Stack Exchange sites, except beta sites, have [a data dump provided by torrent, *about* every six months originally](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/) and recently on a more frequent basis (sometimes every month, sometimes every few months, as far as I am able to see). When they're not listed there, you can find them by searching on [ClearBits](http://www.clearbits.net/).

The most recent data dump was taken on March 2013 (just last month), and [is available here](http://www.clearbits.net/torrents/2121-mar-2013).

There are a variety of ways to search, browse, and view the data; one of them is [this reader](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/708/stackexchange-data-dump-viewer-a-desktop-tool-for-viewing-the-stackexchange-da) by [Nathan Osman](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/5/nathan-osman). If you're interested in processing the file yourself (or exercising a greater degree of control over how it is processed), you should take a look at [this MSO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141562/how-to-read-data-dump-of-a-site) and [that one too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28221/scripts-to-convert-data-dump-to-other-formats).

Comment: I'm pretty sure they upped it to once a week now.

Comment: @Seth Maybe you're thinking of the dump used by the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com). Publicly downloadable data dumps provided by torrents do appear to come out more often than twice a year now (I've updated my answer), but not *every week*.

Comment: Yep. I asked in the Tavern and the data explorer is the on updated weekly.

Comment: When is the next data dump? Is there a way to tell ? @EliahKagan