# Any Stack (ask Ubuntu) software

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tools for Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/75/tools-for-ask-ubuntu)

Is there Any new Stack software for Ubuntu 11.10

So i can manage from desktop

Stack Applet 1.4 is not Working  (not finding my username)

Comment: I've migrated this to meta, assuming your question is about Tools for Ask Ubuntu. As for the bug in stackapplet, the right place to report this is [Stack Applet's Bugtracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/stackapplet). I bet it's already been reported. Hope that helps. And welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Answer (score 3):

You should check the [1.5 beta2](https://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-bringing-stack-exchange-notifications-to-your-desktop-1-5-beta-2) of stackapplet at the moment. That should work.

For additional software for stackexchange and askubuntu you can look here: https://stackapps.com/