# Is there a way to get Desktop notification for AskUbuntu answers/comments?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tools for Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/75/tools-for-ask-ubuntu)

I would like to get desktop notification if someone comments/answers any of my questions in askubuntu or any stackexchange site. Is there a way to get in ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Sorry, I removed my answer, as stackapplet only gets repuatation

Comment: It looks like stackapplet just gives reputation changes which I dont care. I want to get notified of new answers/comments to questions.

Comment: Stackapplet does both of those things, it notifies you of that.