# Askubuntu app for unity

Tags: support

Is there an app/software available which would integrate askubuntu.com into my unity desktop something like GMail notifier.

This would help me to see what all question are posted on the site without logging in the site

Comment: It will be easier to give a good answer if you describe more precisely what features you need and how you want them integrated.

Comment: tracking this issue (Is there a button for that?)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you will like [StackApplet](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18/stackapplet-monitor-your-reputation-and-get-notified-of-comments-v1-5rc1-rel). It's available through [the repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=stackapplet), so you can install it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install stackapplet
```

See also [Tools for Ask Ubuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/75/tools-for-ask-ubuntu).

Comment: I should also point out that the version in the repositories is kind of old (version 1.4) - you can install 1.5 rc3 from the StackApplet PPA.